# unable to get results from postgres in nodejs if callled from nested function

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, pgpool

I have `DB` class which has public static `query` method. There can be multiple connection pools saved in `_coonection_pools` so I am creating a random number then get the pool and execute the query . this is the code

```
static async query(queryInfo: Query): Promise<any> {
    const query = `select * from ${queryInfo.name} ${queryInfo.arguments} as info;`;
    try {
        return this._queryReplicaDB(queryInfo);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("err", err);
        throw err;
    }
}

static async _queryReplicaDB(query: Query): Promise<any> {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this._connection_pools.length);
    
    // get the pool using random number
    const pool = this._connection_pools[randomNumber];

    try {
        const response = await pool.query(query);
        return response.rows[0].info;
    } catch {
        let response;
        // if replica db fails then try with other pools
        for (let i = 0; i < this._connection_pools.length; i++) {
            // iterrate through every pool
            const pool = this._connection_pools[i];
            try {
                response = await pool.query(query);
                break;
            } catch {
                console.log("Error in Pool index: ", i);
            }
        }

        return response.rows[0].info;
    }
}
```

This is return empty `rows` in the response array

but if instead of calling nested `_queryReplicaDB` object this works fine

```
static async query(queryInfo: Query): Promise<any> {
    const query = `select * from ${queryInfo.name} ${queryInfo.arguments} as info;`;
    try {
        const response = await this._connection_pools[0].query(query);
        return response.rows[0].info;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("err", err);
        throw err;
    }   
}
```

i have tried `this._connection_pools[0]` in the `_queryReplicaDB` as well but this does not work.

I tried  random number thing directlty in the `query` method in this method this works.

what can be the issue?

Comment: In the 1st query function, you create a query and don't pass it along, and instead pass queryInfo. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @RaniSharim, thanks yes it worked, i was passing the wrong object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case code was correct, its just I was passing the wrong object type. Instead of passing Query object

```
static async _queryReplicaDB(query: Query): Promise<any> {
```

this function should accept string type as the query

```
static async _queryReplicaDB(query: string): Promise<any> {
```